# All tabs close while Chrome is still running in the background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a code for my Extension to close all tabs after clicking on X?
Because when Chrome is running in the background they reopen the last tabs.

Comment: There is no need for any code to do this; just visit chrome://settings/onStartup and select "Open the New Tab page".

Comment: It was a bug. Thank you. I have to switch it ones after install Google Chrome to apply it.